# Get Checkbox Object from a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a repeater and I am trying to access the Checkbox controller from the LinkButton event.The Repeater controls only contain the literals and linkbuttons but not checkbox controls.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTicketsInPerformance" OnItemDataBound="rptTicketsInPerformance_ItemBound" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cbticketSelect" runat="server" />
   <asp:Literal ID="ltticketDescription" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
   <div class="change-buttons">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btDonate" runat="server" CssClass="button-primary" Text="Donate"  OnClick="donateButton_click" />
   <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCancel" runat="server" CssClass="button-primary close-reveal-modal" Text="Cancel" />
   </div>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void donateButton_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem items = ((sender as LinkButton).Parent as RepeaterItem);
        foreach(var itm in items.Controls)
        {
            if(itm is CheckBox)
            {
              // Do something here
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the `Parent` of the `sender` is actually the `Repeater`, not the Repeater item.

So, you should point to

```
sender.Parent.Items
```

and then iterate over those, and find the `CheckBox`.

Comment: Well I am getting a repeater items as the parent http://imgur.com/a/8mADB

Answer (score 0):

Try this to `FindControl`:

```
protected void donateButton_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem items = ((sender as LinkButton).Parent as RepeaterItem);
    foreach (RepeaterItem itm in items.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)itm.FindControl("cbticketSelect");

        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            Lable1.Text = "Do something ";
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all the Repeater items and use `FindControl` to locate the CheckBox in each item.

```
protected void donateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkedBoxes = "";

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptTicketsInPerformance.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cb = item.FindControl("cbticketSelect") as CheckBox;
        checkedBoxes += cb.Checked.ToString() + ", ";
    }

    Label1.Text = checkedBoxes;
}
```