# ASP Repeater -- access Columns/Cells

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am trying to loop through my Repeater and I am having trouble accessing the Columns/Cells (like you can do with DataGrids or GridViews).  This code is not happening in ItemDataBound, as I am passing the Repeater control to another function to Export to CSV document.  In short, I'm curious if it is possible to access the Cells/Columns for each RepeaterRow?  Or do I have to loop through every control?

Comment: You need to iterate over `reapeater.Items` Collection.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641078/get-checkbox-object-from-a-repeater

Comment: Yes I can iterate through the Items collection.  But I then need a generic approach to then looping through each Cell/Column if it's possible.  10 different Repeaters might use this Function, so I cant use FindControl method.